# picking values from columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas DataFrame with values in a number of columns, make it two for simplicity, and a column of column names I want to use to pick values from the other columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1337)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"a": np.arange(10), "b": 10 - np.arange(10), "c": np.random.choice(["a", "b"], 10)}
)
```

which gives

```
> df['c']

0    b
1    b
2    a
3    a
4    b
5    b
6    b
7    a
8    a
9    a
Name: c, dtype: object
```

That is, I want the first and second elements to be picked from column `b`, the third from `a` and so on.

This works:

```
def pick_vals_from_cols(df, col_selector):
    condlist = np.row_stack(col_selector.map(lambda x: x == df.columns))
    values = np.select(condlist.transpose(), df.values.transpose())
    return values

> pick_vals_from_cols(df, df["c"])

array([10, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9], dtype=object)
```

But it just feels so fragile and clunky. Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [`lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df.lookup(df.index, df.c)

array([10,  9,  2,  3,  6,  5,  4,  7,  8,  9])
```

---

#### Comprehension

But why when you have `lookup`?

```
[df.at[t] for t in df.c.items()]

[10, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

#### Bonus Hack

Not intended for actual use

```
[*map(df.at.__getitem__, zip(df.index, df.c))]

[10, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```

Because `df.get_value` is deprecated

```
[*map(df.get_value, df.index, df.c)]
```

> FutureWarning: `get_value` is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use `.at[]` or `.iat[]` accessors instead

```
[10, 9, 2, 3, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 9]
```